# How to run Linux game (game_name.x64 file) with dedicated GPU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, games, amd-graphics

I recently stumbled upon a Linux game (Art of Rally) on itch.io (see attached screenshot)

I downloaded the zip file and ran the game by changing the permission of the .x64 file extension as "Allow executing file as a program" and the game launched. I changed in game  graphics settings, but still the game lags a lot, and by default it ran on default Intel GPU.

I have another AMD GPU in my laptop, how can I run this game with dedicated GPU of my laptop?

[image: game folder screenshot]

Specs :

Ubuntu 20.4 LTS OS

i5 @ 1.9 GHz (5th gen) CPU

4 GB DDR3 RAM

Intel HD graphics 5500 GPU0

AMD Radeon R5 M330 2 GB GPU1

Comment: Run is with `DRI_PRIME=1`

Comment: @Pilot6 how do and where do I type this command ? can you list whole steps please, I'm new to Linux?

Comment: How do you run the game? So run it with this prefix.

Comment: I run by double clicking the game file

Comment: Run it in a terminal with the prefix. Don't ask how to run in a terminal please.

Comment: right click and opened terminal here inside game folder
input:
< DRI_PRIME=1 artofrally_demo.x64 >

output:
< artofrally_demo.x64: command not found >

Comment: `DRI_PRIME=1 ./artofrally_demo.x64`. Check if the file is there by `ls`

Comment: hey @Pilot6 Thankyou so much for helping me out, as I'm new to Linux I would have been bit annoying to you, but Sincerely thankyou for keeping patience and helping me out, your solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your game in a terminal with `DRI_PRIME=1` prefix.

The game will run on AMD GPU.